# RecusriveDirectoryIterator - Getting files within folder with specific params

Tags: php, iteration

My end-goal is to grab only jpg|png files from within a directory (that has directories in it). I first started with this article: [*List Files and Directories with PHP (Oct 2012; by Aurelio De Rosa)*](http://www.sitepoint.com/list-files-and-directories-with-php/) and settled on the OOP approach (since this seems to be the best way forward).

Of course, with this comes some complexities that I haven't found a good example for thus far. The following example (from [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator)) seems to get me part of the way there, but I haven't found a good way to match all of the requirements (below the example):

```
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST );
$r = array();
foreach ($ritit as $splFileInfo) {
   $path = $splFileInfo->isDir()
         ? array($splFileInfo->getFilename() => array())
         : array($splFileInfo->getFilename());

   for ($depth = $ritit->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) {
       $path = array($ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $path);
   }
   $r = array_merge_recursive($r, $path);
}

print_r($r);
```

What I'd like to do is:

1. Specify a `$directory` (let's say `/media/galleries`)
2. Have it only look at directories first (so if any files are in that top-level directory it ignores them)
3. Check if each directory is readable (it may do this by default already)
4. List out each `jpg|png` file within these files (again, making sure each is readable which I believe it may do by default)
5. Ignore any/all dot files in the `FilesystemIterator` seems to do, but I'm still getting the dreaded `.DS_Store` files in the top-level)
6. Store these as a multi-dimensional array

The aforementioned example seems to be almost there, but any help to steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you ask a lot, I don't understand why read-ability is such a prominent problem to you. If a directory is not readable, the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` can not enter it. It will throw and exception in that case.

To deal with it you need to set a flag in the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to *"catch `getChildren()`"* ([developer feedback](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/479271#479271)) so you might want to specify it:

- [`RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD`](http://php.net/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php#recursiveiteratoriterator.constants.catch-get-child) - it is a flag, not a mode, so use setFlags or the third parameter of the constructor, more/better information there as well: http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct

So this might be one deail you're looking for. Just one pointer hopefully in the right direction (I might extend this later).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked into `CATCH_GET_CHILD` and that definitely does help. The only thing I haven't been able to find is is I'd need to rewrite the snippet or possibly find a flag that I have not to only add directories to the top-level array and skip any dot files in the initial file list as well.

Comment: It works with the getDepth() method however I'm pretty sure you need to create a filter for that. Checkout the `RecursiveFilterIterator`. Keep me updated with your progress.

Comment: I did look into that, but wasn't able to grasp it as of yet. While a bit crude, wouldn't [this way](http://pastebin.com/SEN2bFhu) also work? I'd rather write this in a filter as you mention, the docs just seem to be a bit all over the place as far as being able to access specific file info from within the Iterator classes. At the end of the day, I'd love to be able to parse out different "types" of files within the array, which I should just be able to do with `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` (so I can filter/group my files this way). Again, would rather use RecursiveFilterIterator, but may do it.

Comment: yes, that would work also, albeit getDepth() gives back a number (works also without a filter) and numbers are easier to deal with because more distinct.